# Script to insert data on different domain

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I am thinking about writing a script that will perform a sort of checkout procedure automatically similar to a program like Ebay snipe.

I will know what the page exactly looks like. All I really want to do is load the page from a different domain than the one that is running my script into an iframe, have jquery insert the data into the appropriate fields and then use javascript so click the submit button.

I have been reading about security issues with accessing information across different domains. On the domain I am trying to submit to I would like to call a few jquery functions such as .find() to  get the id of the submit buttons so I can programatically click on them.

This might sound malicious or something which its not there is something going on sale that will sell out quick and I will not be around to click refresh one hundred times to try and buy it. I figured it would be a cool project to make a script that buys it for me.

Anyway my first question is, is this possible? Secondly, what would be the best way to solve this problem? I was going to use PHP/Javascript/Jquery. Will this even work/be allowed. Also if anyone has any other information that might help me out that would be great. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Not going to happen... The only way I think you can accomplish this, for yourself, is by inserting your code with FireBug (or the like) on a per-use basis, or perhaps in a GreaseMonkey configuration... but it's not something that you could publish so that others would get the same functionality just by going to your page.

Comment: So how does Ebay Snipe work? It finds the fields inserts the amount you want and then clicks the buy button right at the last second.

Comment: I believe those kind of utilities are a server side configuration that posts the correct data to where the buy button goes - it doesn't actually execute javascript.

Answer (score 0):

In Firefox, you can create a bookmark that runs JavaScript (instead of navigating to another page). So, now you can inject any javascript into your own page.

With this info, you can load jQuery from another domain along with any other scripts and automate whatever you like.

This only works for you, the person with the special bookmark, but you can hand the bookmark to others for their use.